# Deserialize classes with same interface using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have an interface (called Content) and a couple of classes that implement that interface (e.g. ContentVideo, ContentAd...). I receive a JSON Object that contains a list of those objects. I started out deserializing those objects manually in seperate classes, but recently came across GSON, which would simplify this process immensely. But I'm not sure how to implement this.

Here's ContentVideoJSONParser

```
public ArrayList<ContentVideo> parseJSON(String jsonString) {
        ArrayList<ContentVideo> videos = new ArrayList<>();

        JSONArray jsonArr = null;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                ContentVideo cv = gson.fromJson(jsonObj.toString(), ContentVideo.class);
                videos.add(cv);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return videos;
    }
```

ContentAdJSONParser looks exactly the same, except for returning an ArrayList of ContentAd objects and this line to retrieve the object:

```
ContentAd ca = gson.fromJson(jsonObj.toString(), ContentAd.class);
```

What's the easiest way to combine those to classes into one? Note: one JSON object only contains one class, either ContentVideo or ContentAd. They are not mixed like in other SO questions, which would require a TypeAdapter.

This seems to be a straightforward problem but I can't figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
public <T extends Content> ArrayList<T> parseJSON(String jsonString, Class<T> contentClass) {
    ArrayList<T> contents = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONArray jsonArr = null;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try {
        jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
            T content = gson.fromJson(jsonObj.toString(), contentClass);
            contents.add(content);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return contents;
}
```

Comment: I write Java for Android and T won't be recognized. I now use "class.cast(gson.fromJson(jsonObj.toString(), class));" is this save to do or bad practice?

Comment: That's a bit odd. I must be missing something in my example. If your original code contained generics (`ArrayList<ContentVideo>`), you should be able to compile something similar as well. Please make sure you're not missing the `<T extends Content>` after the `public` keyword.

Comment: oh you're right. I missed that. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Great! No problem!